# Why vectors can't be translated in the context of affine space

Tags: geometry, vectors, affine-geometry

While I'm studying the **Affine Space** lecture materials for the **Computer Graphic** Course, it stated that **point** can be translated to different places since it represents a position, however, the **vector** can't be translated, because it represents motion or direction.

Can anybody elaborate on this idea more? or try to explain it in a different way?

Thanks.

Comment: It's more like vectors don't need to be translated. If I do a change of coordinates by moving up 1 and left 2, then the coordinates of points will all change (the y coordinate by -1, the x coordinate by +2). But the coordinate representation of vectors will not change.

Comment: İ can't get why the coordinate representation of vectors will change after doing a change of coordinates. ?

Comment: Think of a vector in graphics as being like the directed distance between two points. If both points are translated in the same way, then their directed distance remains what it was before.

Comment: A [paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220184234_Illicit_Expressions_in_Vector_Algebra) by Ronald Goldman explains the difference very well in the sense of @MarkSaving's second comment.

Comment: @BobWerner Goldman was actually my professor for my Formal Languages & Automata Theory course, so it's neat to see his name here.